# SQL Query Performance changes due to DATETIME or ODBC literal

Tags: sql-server, datetime, query-performance

I am working on a simple SSRS report. So simple it's not worth going into.
The query is so simple. Again so simple.

The issue that I am experiencing is that there is a big performance drop in management studio based on the use of a DATETIME variable or the ODBC literal.

So then this query

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME = '2015-09-15'
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME = '2015-10-01'
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.HEADER 
WHERE TRANSDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Performs terribly... like 30 seconds on not that many records.

And then this query...

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.HEADER 
WHERE TRANSDATE BETWEEN {ts '2015-09-15 00:00:00.00'} AND {ts '2015-10-01 00:00:00.00'}
```

Runs very quickly... like 0 seconds.

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior for me? In my mind SQL server would treat them both the same, but clearly I am mistaken.

Comment: My guess would be that SQL Server has cached the results of your hard-coded query, but it can't figure out that it can use the same cache with the variables query.

Comment: If you're in BIDS, it can stash the data in a **.data** file in your report folder. It might need to get results every time when it uses a parameter but use the cached data when it's hardcoded.